# How to check all the elements of a stack as the stopping condition in recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have a problem with the stopping condition in a recursive function.

The function takes as inputs

- a state of a graph
- a list of messages(in order) and
- a graph g.

The function traverses the graph and at 
--the initial state (s0): if none of all the outgoing edges is equal to the first element of the list then recursion stop, 
--if at least one of the edges is equal to the first element of the list then it takes that edge and moves to the next state (s1) to check if all the outgoing edges of the reached state (s1) are not equal to the second element of the list (if all of them are not equal, stop and increase counter. If one of them is equal moves to the next state and do the same with third state and third element in the list...etc).

The stopping condition is that all the edges are not equal to the given element of the list (in order). It means if I find an edge at the state of level *k* not equal to the *k*th element of the list, I should continue to check the other edges of the same state (level *k*) till I make sure none is equal to that element of the list then I stop and I increment a counter.
I provide what I have done so far, but it's not working!!

Could you please help. Thanks

```
void DFSUtil(State s, LinkedHashSet<Message> listm, Graph g ){
 State stak2 = new Stack<State>();
 int counting=0;
 Iterator<Message> m = listm.iterator(); 

 for(Edges e1 : g.edgesOutOf(s)){
    stak2.push(e1);
 }
 while(!stak2.empty())
  e2=stak2.pop();
  if(!m.equals(e2.expectedInput)){
    counting++;
  }Else{
        listm.remove(m);
        State newState =new State(e2.getTarget());
        DFSUtil(newState, listm,g);
       }
  System.out.println(counting);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your code and fix all the compilation errors. It's hard to figure out what you are trying to do otherwise. For example  - `m=listm[0];` - `m` is not declared anywhere, and `listm`is not an array.

Comment: what is not working? does the stopping condition fire at all or is causing infinite loop? also, please format your code with proper indentation. we are humans, not compilers

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I don't know how to stop after checking all the edges of a given state.

Comment: Thanks, I did edit the code as suggested. The problem is that I need to stop when all the edges of the state at level _k_ are not equal to the _k_ th element of the given list. Thank you for any suggestions.